# New tag request: resource-recommendations

Tags: feature-request, tags

I don't know whether this site is relatively new, but I don't find an important tag here, that I use often on Physics SE or other science SE.

A new tag should be implemented: 'resource-recommendations'.

This tag shall adhere to all questions which ask for **books, papers or alike**, in the field of electronics, but **not** hardware or software recommendations. It is necessary to have a tag on resource-recommendations so as to enable users to ask for books in this vast topic, as books are the stepping stone to gaining any knowledge in any field.

The help or wiki to the tag may be:

> Questions asking "What is a good book about X?" or more generally, "What should I read to learn about X?", typically where there is not a single authoritative reference.

There is one tag called [reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference), but that neither has a help page, nor are there any questions related to resource-recommendations under it.

Comment: This is one thing we are trying to avoid, so a tag for it would be pointless.  Hmm, unless the system can then automatically close questions with this tag.

Answer (score 4):

Resource recommendations are specifically disallowed here. There are separate sites for that: [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Please take the time to browse the site, including our [guide for newcomers](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) in order to get a better feel for how our question-and-answer system works, including what is on-topic and what is off-topic.

Comment: Resource means **books**, not hardware or software.

Comment: Requests for books are almost universally "too broad" under our topicality rules. Books about narrow topics tend to be quickly superceded. This is one aspect of engineering that is very different from a pure science. Pretty much the only book we ever recommend (to newbies) is [The Art of Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics).

Comment: @DaveTweed Hardware rec isn't great.  I asked for a multimeter recommendation and got nothing: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8345/best-digital-multimeter-for-100-or-less I expect electronics would be flooded with rec requests if allowed but should there be specific allowance for things like academic papers?  That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These are the reasons why we don't go shopping on stack exchange sites: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

These are the list of things [that are off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site:

> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their
>     electronics for other uses
> - Programming software for a PC
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!